# How to retrieve all items from a list by javascript object model and store it to array

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, javascript, client-object-model

I'm new to JavaScript Object Model in SharePoint 2010 and want to get some idea of that.
I wrote below code to get all list items of a SharePoint library. This works fine and return all items. But I want to store the result to a Javascript array. Because I use an API, it requires an array as param.
Like JSArray=allDocs.getEnumerator();// Something like this
Anyidea?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var allDocs;

    $('#btnDemo2').click(function () {
        var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

        var targetList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Shared Documents');
        var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();

        allDocs = targetList.getItems(query);
        ctx.load(allDocs);

        ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, getDocsAllItemsSuccess),
            Function.createDelegate(this, getDocsAllItemsFailure));
    });

    function getDocsAllItemsSuccess(sender, args) {
        var listEnumerator = allDocs.getEnumerator();
        while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            $('#demo2Result').append(listEnumerator.get_current().get_item("FileLeafRef") + '<br />');
        }
    }

    function getDocsAllItemsFailure(sender, args) {
        alert('Failed to get list items. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll get an array back if you use loadQuery rather than load. In the example below allDocs is an array.

```
var targetList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Shared Documents');
var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();

var queryResults = targetList.getItems(query);
var allDocs = ctx.loadQuery(queryResults);
```

Comment: Didn't know of that method, but its actually the same type of collection you get from get_data(), a SP.ClientObjectCollection object

Comment: sorry, I did mean an ArrayList :)

Comment: Be careful though; the reason `getItems` returns something less convenient than an array is so that it can track changes to the items. If you use `loadQuery`, you'll have to manage this yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the result as an `ArrayList` using [SP.ClientObjectCollection.data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee552099(v=office.14).aspx)

Then you can access properties like this:

```
 var listEnumerator = allDocs.get_data();
listEnumerator[0].get_item("FileLeafRef")
```

**Edit:**

If you want an array with only FileLeafRef, you could do something like this:

```
var myArray2 = new Array(); 

allDocs.get_data().map(function(item) {
    myArray2.push(item.get_item("FileLeafRef"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks Anders. Is this fine?   var listEnumerator = allDocs.getEnumerator();
        var myArray2 = new Array();
        myArray2 = allDocs.get_data();
        myArray2[0] = listEnumerator.get_current().get_item("FileLeafRef");

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution First things you need to create the required tags dynamically.I have made some correction in the above.
I have three columns in the list and to fetch them and display individually,I have used three array and created dynamic tags

....Code is here...

```
var hostWebUrl;
var appWebUrl;
// This code runs when the DOM is ready and creates a context object which is needed to use the SharePoint object model
$(document).ready(function () {




    hostWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(manageQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'));
    appWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(manageQueryStringParameter('SPAppWebUrl'));
    Fetchdata();



});

function manageQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
    var params =
    document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    var strParams = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
        if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve) {
            return singleParam[1];
        }
    }
}


function Fetchdata() {
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);//Get the SharePoint Context object based upon the URL  
    var appCtxSite = new SP.AppContextSite(ctx, hostWebUrl);
    var web = appCtxSite.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Announcement");

   // var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    //camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'Title\'/>' +
    //    '<Value Type=\'Text\'>Annoucement1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
    collListItem = list.getItems("");

    ctx.load(collListItem);


    ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemInfo1 = new Array();
    var listItemInfo2 = new Array();
    var listItemInfo3 = new Array();

    var itemCount = 0;

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {


        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

        listItemInfo1[itemCount] = oListItem.get_item('Title');
        //alert(listItemInfo1);
        listItemInfo2[itemCount] = oListItem.get_item('Body');
        listItemInfo3[itemCount]= oListItem.get_item('Images').get_url();
        itemCount++;
        // alert(itemCount);


    }




        for (var i in listItemInfo1) {



        var parent = $('#announcement_slider');


        //Create a div
        var p1 = document.createElement('div');
        parent.append(p1);

        var images = document.createElement('img');
        $(images).attr('src', listItemInfo3[i]);

        $(images).attr('class', 'left mrg_right_10');

        var spanTag = document.createElement('span');

        var spanTag1 = document.createElement('span');
       // alert(listItemInfo3[i]);

        //alert(listItemInfo3[i]);

        spanTag.innerHTML = listItemInfo1[i].toString();
        spanTag1.innerHTML = listItemInfo2[i].toString();






        p1.appendChild(images);

        p1.appendChild(spanTag);
        p1.appendChild(spanTag1);




    }

        $('#announcement_slider').slidesjs({
            height: 50,
            play: {
                active: true,
                auto: true,
                interval: 6000,
                swap: true
            },
            navigation: {
                active: false
            }
        });




    }



function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: if you are doing ==while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {} == inline with ==for (var i in listItemInfo1) {}== you don't need to the for loop, because your while is alreay your loop.